# Set<T> Attribute of Object becomes null after thymeleaf post

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've got a DTO, that contains a set of another DTO. passing that into a thymeleaf template is no problem. How do i retrieve it from the template however?

right now the set attribute is always null

DTO's:

```
public class Partner{
    @Id
    Long id;

    Set<Account> accounts;
}

public class Account{
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;
}
```

Template:

```
<form method="POST" th:object="${partner}" th:action="@{/postmystuff}">
    <div th:each="acc : *{accounts}">
        <input type="text" th:field="${acc}" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController{
    //...
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getMySite(Model m){
        Partner p = new Partner(accounts); //accounts is a set of 10 accounts
        m.addAttribute("partner", p);
        return "mytemplate";
    }

    @PostMapping("/postmystuff")
    public String postMyStuff(@ModelAttribute Partner p){
        System.out.println(p); //for now we just print
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

after submitting, it prints a string representation of the object, however all attributes are null.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added your `Partner` object to the model, so it cannot be accessed by the template. Before your `return` statement, add the line:

```
m.addAttribute("partner", p);
```

Comment: oh i did that. forgot to add that to the question, my bad. but yeah i did that. and it is when reaching the post mapping part that things dont work out. in the postmapping, the print actually prints a partner object, but all its attributes are null